# node's fs.writeFile does not overwrite previous contents

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a file which sometimes gets `\00` null characters inside it. So I need to repair it.

Thats why I'm reading it, removing the invalid characters and writing it again. BUT, `fs.writeFile` is not overwriting its previous contents. The new contents get appended, which is not what i want.

Is is because my write code is inside read code?

```
fs.readFile('./' + file, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    var str = data.toString();
    var repaired = str.slice(0, str.indexOf('\00')) + str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('\00') + 1, str.length);
    //console.log(repaired);
    fs.writeFile('./' + file, repaired, function (err) {
        if (err)
            console.error(err);
    });
});
```

I've also tried using `{flag:'w'}`  (which i think `fs.writeFile` may already have by default)

Comment: If I am not wrong, only the last character of the file will be missing. Can you please verify that?

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes, I guess its a `\n` and it gets removed

Comment: Then I was right. The string being searched for `\00` is not in the file.

Comment: So what? How does that matter? The `\00` will be there sometimes, sometimes it wont be. All I'm doing is writing some content to the file, and its appending instead of overwriting

Comment: Have you considered using `replace` function?

Comment: ahh, I just got it. I tried writing to different file, and still got the contents 2 times. Its not getting the `\00` so its getting the whole file 2 times with slice.

Comment: I'll try for replace. can you post the regex for replace?

Comment: got it. `var repaired = str.replace(/\00/g,'');`
Thanks for pointing to proper direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @[thefourtheye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903116/thefourtheye) for pointing me towards me to proper direction.

As there was no `\00` character in the file i was testing with, the `str.indexOf('\00')` and  was getting the whole file, and again `str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('\00')` was getting the whole file. Thats why I thought

Using replace function did the job.

```
var repaired = str.replace(/\00/g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or similar problem in that it seems when I called fs.writeFile() with different content but the same file, if the new content was shorter than the existing content then it did not overwrite all of the previous file-content.

I found an explanation why this may be happening and a suggested remedy at:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/4965.
According to that "This is not a bug. (Or at least, not one that Node has ever pretended to address...."

The suggested solution is "wait for the callback". I assume that means "wait for the write-callback to be called before trying to read the file". That makes sense of course, you should not try to read what may not have been fully written yet.

But, if you write to the same file several times like I did, then waiting for the (first) write-callback to complete before reading is not enough. Why? Because another 'write' may be in progress when you do the reading, and thus you can get garbled content.